# Как конвертировать массив байтов в Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Есть массив байтов, как его можно преобразовать в картинку?

Так не получается: `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[], 0, byte[].length);` т.к. в Java тип byte имеет диапазон значений от -128 до 127, а у меня и 255 есть и т.д..

Вот сам массив:

```
[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,72,0,72,0,0,255,225,0,88,69,120,105,102,0,0,77,77,0,42,0,0,0,8,0,2,1,18,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,135,105,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,38,0,0,0,0,0,3,160,1,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,160,2,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,41,160,3,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,255,237,0,56,80,104,111,116,111,115,104,111,112,32,51,46,48,0,56,66,73,77,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,56,66,73,77,4,37,0,0,0,0,0,16,212,29,140,217,143,0,178,4,233,128,9,152,236,248,66,126,255,192,0,17,8,0,24,0,41,3,1,17,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,129,145,161,8,35,66,177,193,21,82,209,240,36,51,98,114,130,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,196,0,31,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,129,8,20,66,145,161,177,193,9,35,51,82,240,21,98,114,209,10,22,36,52,225,37,241,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,219,0,67,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,255,219,0,67,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,255,221,0,4,0,6,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,252,179,241,79,237,247,127,226,253,38,219,75,248,127,119,163,104,126,13,212,111,191,178,45,180,200,239,109,180,123,205,98,194,237,44,109,239,53,9,111,88,36,227,78,129,225,187,79,38,237,158,91,184,23,54,195,236,247,81,6,252,238,120,140,119,53,76,36,41,207,13,47,101,57,213,173,120,175,103,40,210,171,39,70,173,74,147,132,37,42,171,145,185,164,148,37,122,114,110,222,255,0,223,97,178,60,44,101,75,25,90,172,113,115,83,167,245,122,42,50,147,146,115,132,57,169,82,140,101,43,69,171,70,43,87,204,154,186,75,151,251,22,255,0,130,38,124,40,210,252,15,251,30,124,33,191,184,211,34,147,89,241,79,133,111,188,105,37,221,205,148,176,106,18,233,26,246,185,170,106,190,25,180,116,120,227,146,59,75,109,18,234,210,104,32,120,210,60,79,36,219,100,121,89,219,210,194,212,196,206,42,181,109,43,213,140,61,188,147,82,188,148,35,27,41,110,210,81,178,105,181,179,86,189,229,203,139,140,35,57,83,135,50,165,78,164,213,56,203,71,27,205,202,73,195,145,56,187,191,133,164,215,117,177,242,23,252,20,183,246,171,248,107,240,243,198,222,41,191,248,85,240,179,194,208,124,91,127,28,233,186,23,197,13,118,102,155,195,22,222,43,251,15,131,226,151,74,213,245,217,244,205,50,238,93,119,88,211,180,214,208,244,155,61,70,242,47,182,13,44,67,97,37,244,182,118,86,80,69,225,113,102,58,142,2,134,19,19,86,157,106,181,170,87,116,33,236,125,159,52,163,200,231,43,243,73,69,168,56,189,126,39,204,246,209,195,222,225,220,21,92,92,170,65,85,140,41,170,74,163,114,92,214,113,154,133,162,147,178,186,147,186,77,246,122,171,199,249,207,248,221,251,98,252,67,248,121,125,225,255,0,26,248,171,225,199,195,143,30,162,157,102,194,214,203,197,87,154,150,170,182,186,190,173,115,164,235,81,107,146,220,67,97,163,201,38,161,18,248,117,44,210,105,210,86,91,52,138,221,60,152,32,72,171,229,56,111,19,131,204,113,152,234,184,106,85,233,99,42,198,21,43,226,235,206,53,43,212,163,74,82,133,58,84,218,118,133,26,126,218,110,20,96,185,19,156,154,140,92,167,41,122,152,206,29,195,209,88,106,184,154,235,23,10,14,175,179,167,82,148,37,24,215,175,42,85,39,136,114,228,187,170,222,30,49,246,147,139,169,201,24,195,153,66,48,71,180,120,83,246,242,248,223,227,191,7,248,127,196,111,31,195,31,14,219,248,146,25,46,96,179,176,240,214,189,120,208,92,125,162,229,46,162,123,137,252,79,111,19,191,155,4,242,9,146,0,179,150,44,118,59,109,172,49,185,228,178,252,118,39,7,71,10,228,240,181,108,229,42,209,132,101,206,149,71,37,78,52,158,173,212,92,254,242,106,82,230,110,91,30,205,12,170,157,106,84,234,58,178,181,72,222,203,91,91,69,239,107,162,75,173,175,165,175,202,142,235,254,26,147,227,31,253,12,126,12,255,0,194,86,239,255,0,154,26,211,253,104,197,255,0,208,52,63,240,58,132,255,0,98,225,255,0,231,236,255,0,240,58,103,255,208,252,18,253,190,190,39,126,203,22,191,180,79,195,215,253,158,110,60,19,99,240,246,123,77,5,126,34,105,126,1,177,130,215,65,182,134,219,93,179,142,225,98,190,142,48,5,229,214,132,247,145,93,182,155,50,98,56,45,165,114,46,11,181,124,124,242,90,217,131,134,34,180,39,39,24,168,168,85,169,83,146,92,151,229,106,138,106,13,187,253,181,125,244,122,163,245,12,6,117,71,46,163,82,132,101,5,46,102,233,214,167,74,156,234,46,104,218,222,213,251,235,150,73,62,88,201,37,229,117,19,251,250,253,155,191,105,127,135,209,233,126,29,139,195,154,157,172,26,68,126,29,209,34,209,237,44,124,179,13,190,137,46,153,111,253,139,29,186,194,74,173,171,105,194,210,59,80,3,34,194,209,230,78,77,93,36,160,227,30,137,37,203,217,43,165,162,237,174,150,81,86,182,141,62,95,18,188,39,46,105,59,201,202,82,147,155,221,182,239,43,190,183,222,238,90,189,116,220,252,110,253,166,60,15,240,103,226,215,252,20,130,47,135,94,63,241,182,163,105,225,127,143,159,15,47,254,50,248,62,202,239,87,183,208,116,207,248,72,116,6,240,255,0,130,252,73,225,171,29,77,25,110,174,245,23,139,73,77,70,29,36,157,150,182,26,162,77,6,25,228,219,227,103,249,28,243,26,241,173,136,138,169,151,225,227,31,99,78,157,94,90,144,197,73,218,172,228,185,85,211,140,85,166,219,229,111,151,147,83,220,203,51,74,120,12,181,83,195,57,195,50,117,156,106,185,83,83,165,60,47,189,42,114,140,155,74,50,140,159,43,138,90,242,222,77,237,45,95,219,19,254,8,239,240,11,226,7,192,207,28,219,248,6,235,226,5,143,196,203,111,15,106,190,33,248,123,0,241,29,156,246,23,254,43,211,52,91,193,164,105,207,109,171,207,107,101,53,182,165,35,13,50,65,45,204,113,91,173,225,186,243,23,203,87,110,60,179,35,203,242,186,142,190,14,149,79,106,233,201,74,53,42,74,106,81,231,85,121,28,181,105,202,112,140,121,175,123,45,149,153,219,131,206,234,226,113,152,92,62,103,82,17,192,85,175,78,150,38,189,56,114,212,161,78,173,233,203,17,30,72,201,205,225,212,253,178,166,213,167,200,225,173,236,127,25,30,34,212,255,0,107,47,130,62,15,176,210,117,123,157,3,79,131,195,254,53,241,119,195,229,240,244,83,104,26,191,137,180,189,91,195,26,165,229,150,186,247,150,246,115,220,50,105,15,170,38,163,103,103,170,172,146,91,220,155,121,124,153,196,77,6,255,0,102,174,79,193,121,134,105,137,246,148,241,43,20,232,81,196,86,168,231,90,158,29,182,148,84,97,47,134,85,33,200,156,160,151,103,105,59,242,196,234,241,110,3,9,74,105,208,157,23,93,211,162,146,161,82,179,167,56,42,244,235,78,9,62,90,117,105,213,139,142,173,198,238,19,228,107,148,183,255,0,11,187,227,255,0,253,59,127,224,61,167,255,0,28,173,255,0,176,120,91,254,159,127,224,117,63,249,89,203,253,161,196,255,0,243,230,135,254,11,137,255,209,254,87,227,255,0,130,78,255,0,193,70,138,220,72,255,0,240,79,223,219,145,64,220,99,135,254,25,83,227,202,134,220,79,202,168,191,15,247,133,10,64,0,179,22,192,39,111,69,243,227,139,197,183,78,63,87,146,90,115,73,210,149,214,155,234,146,230,111,93,109,215,85,107,159,101,245,124,185,66,114,120,202,23,73,242,65,87,166,226,223,110,94,117,37,20,150,157,118,118,87,63,170,95,216,175,225,103,237,135,224,159,135,63,178,214,157,226,207,217,55,246,185,208,60,87,115,240,190,219,194,62,35,183,213,127,103,15,141,182,75,161,220,252,50,185,58,93,156,158,42,188,184,240,82,90,248,125,245,93,44,64,52,148,215,38,179,125,102,41,36,123,4,158,56,164,116,242,241,24,122,234,173,105,66,141,89,46,119,47,118,13,223,218,94,94,237,163,239,90,252,175,149,233,125,121,108,220,186,105,98,112,146,163,24,203,19,135,141,163,167,53,122,122,37,21,23,118,228,157,214,141,94,73,233,162,149,143,12,255,0,130,205,126,199,31,183,23,196,75,223,130,122,159,194,47,217,87,246,142,241,165,239,135,60,77,241,45,46,47,252,17,240,11,226,215,139,47,52,125,47,90,176,240,77,254,143,43,63,135,124,45,125,113,101,25,146,194,230,219,124,143,18,73,123,13,202,39,204,142,169,117,232,251,84,165,83,15,139,159,42,140,99,78,148,28,121,185,148,92,185,220,162,214,150,209,219,77,85,213,212,141,240,88,202,84,185,163,71,27,151,211,82,75,154,117,234,197,242,186,110,92,188,138,51,73,182,155,90,233,102,159,42,78,241,252,175,210,255,0,224,156,159,240,90,223,28,216,90,253,171,246,119,253,179,96,178,88,18,59,59,63,19,248,19,226,126,149,5,181,177,85,64,131,77,215,153,231,179,12,138,190,101,187,233,209,72,161,21,36,136,99,106,124,206,55,51,194,224,228,233,60,155,136,241,74,45,197,253,91,39,206,177,23,123,217,79,15,151,170,115,91,165,40,213,146,182,169,171,169,30,222,25,194,170,246,159,219,89,13,9,75,190,39,46,166,247,221,170,216,185,74,13,239,239,65,61,116,181,253,219,214,223,240,67,63,248,41,142,178,226,231,196,95,1,126,51,105,173,57,103,187,223,240,215,226,125,244,225,221,139,177,88,244,159,2,50,49,44,75,49,251,81,44,196,146,220,138,240,107,241,117,106,23,88,78,7,226,202,237,105,6,248,115,48,167,22,173,173,229,93,74,87,125,19,166,188,173,119,203,233,67,7,131,170,212,171,241,102,81,7,111,126,49,206,112,11,209,71,216,184,164,187,251,242,249,94,242,245,239,248,113,127,237,201,255,0,68,159,227,183,254,25,143,140,159,252,207,86,95,235,174,117,255,0,68,15,17,127,225,147,23,255,0,204,130,254,206,201,255,0,232,169,203,127,240,249,67,255,0,151,159,255,217]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение вопроса:

```
int[] inArr = [255,216,255 /*...*/];
byte[] data = toByteArray(inArr);

public byte[] toByteArray(int[] data){
    byte[] bytes = new byte[data.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte)  (data[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Названия методов и переменных пишутся с маленькой буквы. (`IntArrayToByteArray`, `Iarr`)

Comment: @anber Считаете что можно улучшить ответ? Исправьте.

Comment: @Cerbo Это скорее добрый совет автору. Если у же на то пошло, то я бы еще дал человеческие названия идентификаторам, отформатировал код, и дал бы описание почему в данном случае нужно сделать именно так, но ведь это будет уже не ответ автора, не так ли?

Comment: @Ilnar Есть соглашение по оформлению кода Java. Отступление от него первый признак низкой квалификации автора. А когда подразумевается что другие будут пользоваться вашим кодом он должен быть еще качественнее оформлен.

Answer (score 2):

Инициализируйте его как массив `int` и из него создайте массив `byte`.

Примерно так:

```
int[] inArr = [255,216,255 ...];
byte[] outArr = new byte[inArr.length];
for (int i=0; i<inArr.length; i++) {
  outArr[i] = (byte)(inArr[i] - 128);
}
```